# Xcode: how to make localized string files work if the file name is not Localizable.strings, how to localize a static lib project?

Tags: xcode, localization

Question 1:
I'm following http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-localize-your-project-in-xcode-4-4/ to create localized strings for my hello world project. The localization cannot work, until I changed the file name from Localized.strings to Localizable.strings. Seems only the file "Localizable.strings" is recognized? In my real project, I would like several string files for different modules, what should I do then?

Question 2:
Now I'm trying to localize a static library project. I follow the exact steps as above and use Localizable.strings as the file name. The files are added to the library project. However, result is the string not localized at all. Why and how could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, `NSLocalizedString` is looking for Localizable.strings. As Jim says, you can however use `NSLocalizedStringFromTable` to specify another strings file.

For question 2, this could well be related to your first question. If you're including your library in a project that itself has a Localizable.strings file, then there will be a conflict (and unfortunately XCode doesn't warn you about it) and only one of the two Localizable.strings file will be in your app bundle. If that's the case, the solution is to use a different name, as per the answer to question 1.

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1, you can use the function: 
    NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"aString", @"fileName", nil)

It returns a localized NSString where fileName is a file containing aString to be localized.

Also, fileName should have an extension of .strings